# php get visibility

Tags: php, visibility, access-modifiers

Is it possible to get the visibility of methods and properties inside a class in php?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function __call($method, $args)
{
    if(is_callable(array($this,$method))
    {
        if(get_visibility(array($this,$method)) == 'private')
            //dosomething
        elseif(get_visibility(array($this,$method)) == 'protected')
            //dosomething
        else
            //dosomething
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's probably doable if you use reflection but I couldn't vouch for the performance.  Also I can't think of any circumstance where you would need to be able to do this.  Maybe you're better off thinking about why you want to do this, and whether it's really necessary.  You don't want to be cluttering your code up with complexity and magic you don't need.

Comment: A use case for knowing the visibility is if you are attempting to emulate the precision of the built-in PHP errors when implementing magic method `__get()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider using PHP's [Reflection API](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) for this. However, I should also ask you *why* you want to do this, because Reflection usually only gets used in situations that are a bit hacky to begin with. It is possible though, so here goes:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    /**
     *
     * @var ReflectionClass
     */
    protected $reflection;
    protected function bar( ) {

    }

    private function baz( ) {

    }

    public function __call( $method, $args ) {
        if( ( $reflMethod = $this->method( $method ) ) !== false ) {
            if( $reflMethod->isPrivate( ) ) {
                echo "That's private.<br />\n";
            }
            elseif( $reflMethod->isProtected( ) ) {
                echo "That's protected.<br />\n";
            }
        }
    }

    protected function method( $name ) {
        if( !isset( $this->methods[$name] ) ) {
            if( $this->reflect( )->hasMethod( $name ) ) {
                $this->methods[$name] = $this->reflect( )->getMethod( $name );
            }
            else {
                $this->methods[$name] = false;
            }
        }
        return $this->methods[$name];
    }

    protected function reflect( ) {
        if( !isset( $this->reflection ) ) {
            $this->reflection = new ReflectionClass( $this );
        }
        return $this->reflection;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo( );
$foo->baz( );
$foo->bar( );
```

Comment: I wanted to do this is because I was just experimenting with simulating multiple inheritance in php. But to get that fully functional, I need to be able to distinguish private and protected methods. offtopic: what a coincidence, we're both from holland, and got the same last name

Comment: Hah, quite the coincidence indeed. Did you read up on the RFC for horizontal reuse in PHP, which has been committed to the trunk a while ago? If not, check it out here; http://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits

Comment: I've read it now. I hope it will be in the next release or so for PHP, but I have to say, to me it just seems like multiple inheritance for methods only, so I don't really see why this is so much better than mi. (E.g. you still have to solve the diamond problem manually)

Comment: +1 for answering the question in spite of the fact that you thought what the poster is doing might be a bad idea.

Comment: @tiddo Multiple inheritance is a misfeature, and there's good reason why so few OO languages support it.  You can use PHP traits along with an interface to accomplish similar functionality but I've never had to and I'd argue that traits are also a misfeature.

Answer (score 7):

`is_callable` takes visibility into account, but since you are using it from inside the class it will always evaluate to `TRUE`.

To get the method visiblity, you have to [use the Reflection API and check the method's modifiers](http://de.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.getmodifiers.php)

**Abridged example from PHP Manual:**

```
class Testing
{
    final public static function foo()
    {
        return;
    }
}

// this would go into your __call method
$foo = new ReflectionMethod('Testing', 'foo');
echo implode(
    Reflection::getModifierNames(
        $foo->getModifiers()
    )
); // outputs finalpublicstatic
```

The same is available for [properties](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php).

However, due to the complexity of reflecting on a class, this can be slow. You should benchmark it to see if it impacts your application too much.

Comment: I just did a quick benchmark, it seems that checking if a method has a certain visibility and then calling the method is about 3 times slower then calling the method directly. For large methods this can be negligible, but for smaller methods (or properties), this isn't.

Comment: @Tiddo take into account that using `__call` or `__get` in the first place is already quite slow. So unless your benchmark lists individual function calls your interpretation of the results might be wrong. On a sidenote, you are better off solving multiple inheritance through interfaces and composition/aggregation and strategies and decorators.

Comment: I know, but I tested it without the __call or __get methods: I called a function a few hundred times from from outside the class with and without the modifier checking. I know I'd better solve these problems through interfaces etc. but in some cases it's just much easier to solve these problems with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is a bit late, but I feel there is still some added value by mentioning [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/get_class_methods) in combination with [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
<?php
class Foo {
    // ...
    public function getVisibility($method) {
        if ( method_exists($this, $method) && in_array($method, get_class_methods($this)) ) {
            return 'protected or public';
        } else {
            return 'private';
        }
    }
}
```